# Split table in (postgreSQL) randomly 50/50

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns in postgresql: original id and duplicate id.

Sample data:

```
original_id   duplicate_id  
     1             1
     2             2
     3             3
     4             4
     5             5
     6             6
```

I would like to randomly split this table in 50/50, so I can put a specific tag in each

Sample data:

```
original_id   duplicate_id     tag
     1             1         control
     2             2         treatment
     3             3         treatment
     4             4         control
     5             5         treatment
     6             6         control
```

What is important:
1. The selection has to be random
2. The split has to be 50/50 (or the closest to this if the number of rows is odd)

Comment: Maybe you can use the random() function and a CASE statement. If random() < .5 return control else return treatment. Manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can select half of the rows in a random order with this query:

```
select *
from my_table
order by random()
limit (select count(*)/ 2 from my_table)
```

Use it to tag the rows:

```
with control as (
    select *
    from my_table
    order by random()
    limit (select count(*)/ 2 from my_table)
)
select 
    *, 
    case when t in (select t from control t) then 'control' else 'treatment' end
from my_table t;
```

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/DYZX80433)

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum <= cnt / 2
             then 'treatment' else 'control'
        end) as tag
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over () as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by random() as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Actually, random is random.  So, you don't need the count.  You can use modulo arithmetic instead:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by random()) % 2 = 1
             then 'treatment' else 'control'
        end) as tag
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rownumber() OVER (ORDER BY random())` to assign a random number to each record. Then use it in a `CASE` to assign either the tag `'control'` or `'treatment'` depending on the number being less than (or equal) than the half of the count of rows in the table or not.

For a `SELECT` that looks like this:

```
SELECT original_id,
       duplicate_id,
       CASE
         WHEN rn <= (SELECT count(*) / 2
                            FROM elbat) THEN
           'control'
         ELSE
           'treatment'
       END tag
       FROM (SELECT original_id,
                    duplicate_id,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) rn
                    FROM elbat) x;
```

If you want an `UPDATE` (I'm not sure on this), assuming, that the pair of `original_id` and `duplicate_id` is unique, this could look like:

```
UPDATE elbat t
       SET tag = CASE
                   WHEN rn <= (SELECT count(*) / 2
                                      FROM elbat) THEN
                     'control'
                   ELSE
                     'treatment'
                 END
       FROM (SELECT original_id,
                    duplicate_id,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) rn
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE x.original_id = t.original_id
             AND x.duplicate_id = t.duplicate_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0a1085020657d138d23d2e5d07d07c51)
(BTW, that `SELECT` result on the Fiddle gives a nice example, that the order of the rows returned can be totally different from the physical one, if the optimizer likes it better that way.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `random()` generate the values 1 or 2 using the formula: `(random() + 1)::int`

```
select t.*,
       case (random() + 1)::int
         when 1 then 'treatment' 
         else 'control'
       end as tag
from t;
```

---

In general, `(random() * (upper_limit - 1) + lower_limit)::int` will generate numbers between upper_limit and lower_limit (inclusive). If upper limit is 2 then the multiplication can be removed (because it would be `* 1` which doesn't change anything), but if you want to e.g. generate four random values you can use that as well:

```
select t.*,
       case (random() * 3 + 1)::int
         when 1 then 'treatment' 
         when 2 then 'control'
         when 3 then 'something'
         else 'some other thing'
       end as tag
from t;
```

Comment: This would be a great solution, unfortunately it does not guarantee even distribution in partitions. You may get e.g. 5/1 (5 `treatment` and 1 `control`) as well as 1/5 or 4/2 etc.